# Javascript Boolean comparator from string

Tags: javascript, sql, boolean

Unusual question here and maybe I'm approaching this issue incorrectly -

I'd like to do a comparison between some numeric values in Javascript, but I have the comparators stored in a database (in a VARCHAR field), where specific criteria are stored. (Comparators being <=, <, ==, >, >=, etc).

Is there a way to evaluate the string returned as a comparator in JS?

Thanks

Comment: `eval` function. read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: if you're comparing string it will only compare the first character if that is the same the second etc. if you want to compare numeric values use [parseint](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

Comment: Something like `switch (cmp) case '<=': ...` is your sanest bet.

Comment: I had the switch() solution implemented already, but thought I'd extend the question here to maybe find a more 'purist' solution. +1 to suggesting the eval() function. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **is**, but unless you're using it with **completely trusted data**, don't use it.

Instead, implement the comparisons:

```js
function compare(operator, operand1, operand2) {
    switch (operator) {
        case "<=":
            return operand1 <= operand2;
        case ">=":
            return operand1 >= operand2;
        // ...and so on...
    }
}
```

But yes, if you **fully trust** the data, you can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
function compare(operator, operand1, operand2) {
    return eval("operand1 " + operator + " operand2");
}
```

(That looks like pseudo-code, but it isn't; `eval` evaluates the code string you give it in the context where you call it, so it has access to the `operand1` and `operand2` arguments.)

The "trust" part there is really, really important, because `eval` allows executing any script code. If you're allowing Bob to provide data that will eventually be evaluated in a browser by Alice, **don't** use `eval`. It's a major security risk to Alice.

Comment: Thanks TJ, was looking for something like this :) Just regarding the code sample you provided for the compare function, will operand1 and operand2 not evaluate completely as strings due to the positions of the literals?

Comment: @N15M0_jk: No, they aren't converted to strings (in the code above). They retain whatever type they have when passed to `compare`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use an object with the comparators as key and return a function for making the comparison.

```
var comparison = {
    '<=': function (a, b) { return a <= b; },
    '<':  function (a, b) { return a < b; },
    '==': function (a, b) { return a == b; },
    '>':  function (a, b) { return a > b; },
    '>=': function (a, b) { return a >= b; },
    default: function () { return false; }
}
```

Usage:

```
(comparison[comp] || comparison.default)(value1, value2);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, I'm considering doing something like this - but was wondering if there's an even deeper way to evaluate a string as a boolean comparator?

Comment: it depends. do you have an example?

Comment: Looking at TJs answer above, the eval() function executes code, regardless of it being trustworthy. In my mind I was trying to identify something similar to casting a string to a boolean, but instead as the comparator/operator

Comment: @N15M0_jk: Nina's mapping object above comes fairly close to that. It basically lets you get a function equivalent of an operator. I'd probably wrap that map up in a function: `function getOperator(opname) { return comparison[opname] || comparison.default; }` And then using it: `var op = getOperator(">="); if (op(operand1, operand2)) { ... }` It's very like my `compare` function with the `switch`, but inverted, encapsulating each operator as a function. Which makes good sense; at a comp sci level, operators *are* functions, just ones with a more convenient notation.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to write your own `compare` method and keep results/codes on DB something like

```
function compare(a, b):
    if( a < b ) return -2;
    else if (a <= b) return -1; 
    else if ( a == b) return 0;
    //...
```

and then keep values of `0`, `-1`, `-2` on db

Now, if you want to apply some comparator from your DB you just call `compare` on your string and check whether the result is the same as code from DB or not (and it will give you *True* or *False*)

The only problem here is that you need to fire all comparisions on dataset but it is completely safe and also will handle some inappropriate operators (that cannot be applied for a strings) - the only requirement is that code on DB must be a key

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var comparator = '<=';
var result = eval(a + comparator + b)
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax call to retrieve the string operator from server side code and then evaluate the string for comparison in javascript code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "retrieveOperator.php", success: function(result){

    switch(String(result)) {
        case "==":
            code block for == operator
            break;
        case ">=":
            code block for >= operator
            break;
        default:
            default code block
    }   
    });
});
</script>
```